# Function prop from parent is undefined at first - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'll try to keep it as simple as possible. I've got these 2 components - parent -> child. The problem is when I click the button, nothing happens.

When I try to console.log(props.handleClick) in the Button component, it logs 'undefined' at first and right after that the actual function.

So the console logs this:

```
undefined
function handleClick() {
  return console.log("Hello");
}
```

It seems like that the parent component fails at passing the function at first or something like that. Have you got any idea what could be wrong?

### components

Parent component:

```
class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <Button handleClick={() => console.log("Hello")} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Button component

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return <button onClick={props.handleClick}>Hello</button>;
};
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t5e92dzm/1/ I used your code and it works with no problem.

Comment: I see. Hmm, I guess there could be some problem with webpack then. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe babel is not setup correctly?